# AES_cbc_encrypt encryption does not work correctly for release on mac os

Tags: macos, encryption, aes, release

I encrypt a message to the client (c ++), using aes, server (C #) decrypts it. Everything is OK if the build Debug client on the Release the server says that it can not decrypt the message if the message is a variable (int64_t) with a value greater than 127, if it is less than ok

structure of the message

```
class version : public ::google::protobuf::Message
{

string* software_;
int64_t version_;
};
```

my code

```
uint32_t encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char **out, uint32_t size)
{
/**
 * tresh - ivec change after AES_cbc_encrypt
 */
unsigned char _ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
memcpy(&_ivec, &ivec, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
/**/

uint32_t size_out = this->getBlockSize(size);
unsigned char *in_padding = (unsigned char*)malloc(size_out);
memset(in_padding, size_out - size, size_out);
memcpy(in_padding, in, size);

AES_KEY _key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, PK_SIZE_KEY*BITS_IN_BYTE, &_key);
AES_cbc_encrypt(in_padding, *out, size_out, &_key, _ivec, AES_ENCRYPT);

free(in_padding);

return size_out;
};

uint32_t getBlockSize(uint32_t size)
{
if((size % AES_BLOCK_SIZE) != 0){
    size /= AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    size += 1;
    size *= AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
}
return size;
};
```

how to fix it? very strange

Answer (score 0):

changed the code and ok

```
uint32_t getBlockSize(uint32_t size)
{
size /= AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
size += 1;
size *= AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
return size;
};
```